# How to run build in a parent directory, copy build into current directory before deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

My friend had a bad folder structure, which he wanted me to contribute to, he had his backend in the client directory.

[image: folder structure of project]

i wanted to separate the folder, he objected, so as not to loose previous git commit history. so i came up with this approach of running a script before deploying

[image: dev script before deploy]

i.e enters the client removes previous client build, runs new build and copy to backend. in the backend i serve the client build as a static file.
so after committing changes in both client and backend i ran

```
   npm run dev
   git push heroku
```

This approach worked very well, but i want only heroku or npm to run it before deploying, i tried changing my dev script to heroku-postbuild, heroku-prebuild, npm postinstall, and even build, but the build kept failing.

heroku-postbuild

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd ../ && rm -rf build && npm run build && cp -rf ./build ./backend/public",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

heroku-prebuild

```
 "scripts": {
            "start": "node server",
            heroku-prebuild": "cd ../ && rm -rf build && npm run build && cp -rf ./build ./backend/public",
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
          },
```

it kept throwing this error, 
[image: deploy error]

and i understand why the error occurs, " cd ../" in the heroku-prebuild script refers to the client, which doesnt exist in the heroku repo i am deploying. pls what other approach can you recommend for me.

Comment: What is the benefit of moving the backend directory at build time? It seems like the benefit of having a separate backend directory would be in the development environment.

Comment: i am not moving the backend directory

Comment: at backend build time , i want to enter in the the client dir(ireact app, .e. which is also the parent directory), and run build for client, and then copy client build folder into backends public folder, there is no actuall build for the backend itself.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I'm not really understanding the file structure here. If you change directories the the parent directory, you'll be at root outside of the `app/` directory. Have you tried poking around with `heroku run bash`?